# Deoplete doesn't work for neovim in ArchLimux

Tags: archlinux, neovim

I'm trying to use neovim with deoplete on ArchLinux. Both requires Python support.
I've installed `neovim` plugin and `python-neovim`, `python2-neovim` extra plugins with pacman to use python.
This is my extra simple neovim configs:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

if has('nvim')
  Plug 'Shougo/deoplete.nvim', { 'do': ':UpdateRemotePlugins' }
else
  Plug 'Shougo/deoplete.nvim'
  Plug 'roxma/nvim-yarp'
  Plug 'roxma/vim-hug-neovim-rpc'
endif
let g:deoplete#enable_at_startup = 1

" Initialize plugin system
call plug#end()
```

But deoplete autocompletion doesn't work for me.
I've run `:checkhealth` and this is the result:

```
health#deoplete#check
========================================================================
## deoplete.nvim
  - OK: exists("v:t_list") was successful
  - OK: has("timers") was successful
  - OK: has("python3") was successful
  - OK: Python3.5+ was successful
  - INFO: If you're still having problems, try the following commands:
    $ export NVIM_PYTHON_LOG_FILE=/tmp/log
    $ export NVIM_PYTHON_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
    $ nvim
    $ cat /tmp/log_{PID}
    and then create an issue on github
```

Could someone explaine me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add the result of the suggested debug commands in `:checkhealth` ?

Comment: I have no suggestions there.

Comment: After doing `export NVIM_PYTHON_LOG_FILE=/tmp/log; export NVIM_PYTHON_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG; nvim`, the `/tmp/log_{PID}` file is empty ?

Comment: @gileri Thank you for your help. It seems to me that I've fixed the problem after I run `pip3 install --user --upgrade pynvim` to install neovim-python version. I had to do it despite the fact I had installed `python-neovim` AUR package.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly sure you need neovim-python or `python-pynvim` which is a community repo in the AUR.

After that just run `pip3 install --user --upgrade pynvim` and you ought to be settled.

**edit:** just noticed that the answer was suggested in the comments below, and that it is confirmed to be working. Nice!